# How can I make an Arithmetic Underflow in this piece of code?

Tags: c, visual-studio, security

I'm working on some vulnerability tests using Visual Studio 2019 and I'm struggling to get this last one.

I have seen that there is another post about this but I would like to get an aritmetic overflow in this case in particular, without floating point.

I proceed to explain the problem:

Knowing that an unsigned char has a range from 0 to 255, my intention is to exceed the lower range. To achieve this I have used a for loop so I could be able to follow the behavior of the program with breaking points and the debuger.

I did a similar test with the Arithmetic Overflow, and exactly the same thing happened, because of that I was forced to exaggerate the arithmetic operation to finally exceed the upper limit and get finally the overflow. So I think that the compiler itself is doing some kind of recast to prevent such failures from occurring and this way "protect" the programmer.

This is the code:

```
int main()
{
    unsigned char a = 10;
    printf("%hhu\n", a);
    for (int cont =100; cont > 0; cont--) 
    {
        a -= 1;
    }
    printf("%hhu\n", a);
    return  0;
}
```

I would like, on the one hand, to be able to get the aritmetic underflow and on the other hand, know if this is some kind of visual studio functionality and if it is possible to disable it in any way, since I would like a compilation of the code as such it is, without any readjustment.

Thanks you all!
See you soon.

Comment: You can't underflow an unsigned type, simple as that. They use wrap-around, which is well-defined. You will get the value 166 on any system, completely portable.

Comment: I'd like to add that you should probably use the `%hhu` format specifier, because thats the correct one for an unsigned char (`%d` is for signed int)

Comment: @FelixG My fault, thanks for the feedback, I will change it right now.

Comment: Thanks @Lundin I didn't know that. So the only way to get an arithmetic underflow would be to do it with floating point?

Comment: @Commodore Or signed integers.

Comment: Well, technically there is an underflow. It is just not acted upon. Or you could argue that the operations are all modulus 2^8 = 256 in which case there is no such thing as underflow.